# In jsfiddle jquery validate plugin is not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/zj7F8/

Its not firing, where i missed? can you help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jZVA2/

If I may suggest read the plugin again. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ **documentation** http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Few things are missing:

- Name tag
- class required
- Submit button type `submit`
- `script`

Hope it fits your needs `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainForm').validate();
});​
```

Bit complicated version here: http://jsfiddle.net/AvJNk/

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: how can I use the id for reference instead of attr name?

Comment: @Sivasenthil read here: this will help `:)` http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-validating-on-input-id-instead-of-name

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your input type button to submit
and
Remember that it work on your name attribute not on your id like below

```
<input type="text" name="mytxtName" id="mytxtId" />
```

will have code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainForm').validate({
     rules: {
     mytxtName: {
        required: true
     }
 }
});});
```

check working code [here...](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7F8/18/)