# Jquery Validate radio type

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know how to get the radio field type to validate correctly display in the error div? right now it's not validating at all

```
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/lib/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    div.error { height: 15px; overflow: hidden; }
    .cmxform p.error label { color: #FFFF00; font-size: 13px; }
    label.error, label.error { color: #FFFF00; font-size: 13px; }
    div.container { display: none }
    .container label.error { display: inline; }
    form.cmxform label.error { display: block; width: auto; }
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});

$().ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#form1 div.error")
    });
    var container = $('div.container');
});
</script>
```

Form

```
<form method="post" class="cmxform" id="form1" action="">
    <div class="error"></div>
        <input class="inputxt {required:true,minlength:3}" title="fill-in all fields" name="name" />
        <input type="radio" name="website" value="Yes" validate="required" /> YES 
        <input type="radio" name="website" value="No" /> NO
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might come handy: http://jsfiddle.net/kDyRm/

Made it from one of my previous replies here: [In jsfiddle jquery validate plugin is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048361/in-jsfiddle-jquery-validate-plugin-is-not-firing)

Also found this quite handy: http://jsfiddle.net/Bd688/7/

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ **documentation** http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

hope the demos fits the cause `:)`

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is set one of the members of the radio set to be required and jquery will take care of the rest:

```
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="blue" class="required"> Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="red"> Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="green"> Green
```

The above would require at least 1 of the 3 radio options w/ the name of "my options" to be selected before proceeding.

The label suggestion by Mahes, btw, works wonderfully!